# limit UIImagePicker Camera View to a small part of screen

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I am developing an app which uses UIImagePicker to capture and save screen.
Following is the code to launch camera.

```
UIImagePickerController *imgPickController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imgPickController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imgPickController.delegate =self;
imgPickController.allowsEditing=YES;
[self presentModalViewController:imgPickController animated:YES];
```

This launches the camera in the whole screen.

Is there any way to just show the camera-view inside another small subview on the app-screen?? Hope I am clear. Thanks.